# Enable Unity to resolve dependencies from OwinContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

I've a ASP.NET Web Application that uses Microsoft Identity 2.0 and Unity.Mvc for dependency injection.

Microsoft Identity 2.0 registers `UserManager` and `SignInManager` within `OwinContext` and is dependent on `HttpContext`.

I want to inject these within `ManageController`

```
class ManageController
{
    public ManageController(IUserManager userManager, ISignInManager signInManager)
    {
    }
}
```

However that raises an exception as these are yet not registered within `UnityContainer`.

I haven't found any method within `UnityContainer` to register type with object initialized through delegate. something like that

```
container.RegisterInstance<IUserManager>(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>());
```

I also tried to get instance from OwinContext and register that within `UnityContainer`

```
var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>();
container.RegisterInstance<IUserManager>(userManager);
```

However `HttpContext.Current` is `null`.

Is there anyway to customize `UnityContainer` type mapping behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that purpose you can write your custom `UnityContainerExtension` and inside that extension add new strategy with `UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping`, within that strategy, you can override `PreBuildUp` method and resolve type from `OwinContext`

This is how I did it in my own project:

```
public class IdentityResolutionExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    public IdentityResolutionExtension(Func<IOwinContext> getOwinContext)
    {
        GetOwinContext = getOwinContext;
    }

    protected Func<IOwinContext> GetOwinContext { get; }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Strategies.Add(new IdentityTypeMappingStrategy(GetOwinContext), UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping);
    }

    class IdentityTypeMappingStrategy : BuilderStrategy
    {
        private readonly Func<IOwinContext> _getOwinContext;

        private static readonly MethodInfo IdentityTypeResolverMethodInfo =
            typeof (OwinContextExtensions).GetMethod("Get");

        public IdentityTypeMappingStrategy(Func<IOwinContext> getOwinContext)
        {
            _getOwinContext = getOwinContext;
        }

        public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
        {
            if (context.BuildComplete || context.Existing != null)
                return;

            var resolver = IdentityTypeResolverMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(context.BuildKey.Type);
            var results = resolver.Invoke(null, new object[]
            {
                _getOwinContext()
            });

            context.Existing = results;
            context.BuildComplete = results != null;
        }
    }
}
```

For more information about registering `UnityContainerExtension` [see this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660845%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)